# How to plot using psplot a function with very large numbers

Tags: pstricks

Here is my code:

The function does not fit in my document. I played with
lots of numbers for Dx, Dy, xunit, yunit....

It is a nightmare.

Thanks for your help.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\psset{plotpoints=200,algebraic}
\begin{pspicture}
\psaxes[Dx=5, Dy=10]{->}(0,0)(20,4000)
\psplot[algebraic=true, yMaxValue=400, linecolor=black,linewidth=1.5pt]
{0}{20.0}{x^9 * EXP(-x)}
\rput[l](0,20){$x^9 \, \mathrm{exp}^{-x}$}
\end{pspicture}
\newline
\newline
\newline
\newline
\caption{Integrand $t^{x-1} \mathrm{e}*{-t}$.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

**Update:**

I solved my problem by scaling down the function, but... why pstricks does not scale the plot to fit a given box size?  Here is my partial solution and below that the plot that I get:

```
begin{figure}[!ht]
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\psset{plotpoints=200,algebraic, xunit=0.4cm, yunit=2cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(20,1)
  \psaxes[Dx=5, Dy=1]{->}(0,0)(21,1)
\psplot[algebraic=true, yMaxValue=1, linecolor=black,linewidth=1.5pt]
{0}{20.0}{x^9 * EXP(-x)/47811}
\rput[l](0.2,1){$x^9 \, \mathrm{e}^{-x}$}
\rput[l](20,0.2){$x$}
\end{pspicture}
\newline
\newline
\newline
\newline
\caption{Integrand $t^{x-1} \mathrm{e}{-t}$.}
\label{bernoulli}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: You can scale it in an easier way. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis is plotted without knowing anything about the plot. The reason why 
you can scale it yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering
\psset{plotpoints=200,algebraic}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-0.5)(11,5.5)
  \psset{xunit=0.5}
  \psaxes[Dx=5,ylabelFactor=\cdot10^4]{->}(0,0)(20,5)[$x$,90][$x^9\mathrm{e}^{-x}$,0]
  \psplot[linewidth=1.5pt]{0}{20.0}{x^9*EXP(-x)/10000}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{Integrand $t^{x-1} \mathrm{e}*{-t}$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks good. You scaled by 1/10000 and labeled it correctly.